# Can I disobey my parents when they don't allow me to work?

Tags: parents, work

I'm 15 years old, and I finally found a job, but my parents tell me that I shouldn't work and I should tend to my studies. See, I tend to my studies, and I just need some cash, and I give every single penny I earn to my parents for their use, taking only 20 to 30 dollars a week. Am I allowed to work, or do I have to listen to my parents? Because I heard that you are allowed to disobey your parent sin obeying Allah, but isn't working and earning money a way of obeying Allah?
Jazakum allahu khayran.

Comment: The given answers and discussion clearly show that this advice request is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should obey your parents until it goes against The Rules of Allaah Ta'ala.

And now, you decide whether you working while making your parents unhappy is obeying the rules of Allaah or not.

Besides, you may discuss about it with your parents and show them that extra-earning isn't affecting your study.

In that case, you parents might not mind over your part-time working.

Comment: I indeed approve your first answer as the right concise response of the inquiry as you remarked you should obey your parent unless their orders be against Allah. This presented Formula can indeed help us.

Answer (score -1):

Your Question seems to me kind of opinion based, but i'll try to answer it to the best of my knowledge according to my interpretation of the relationship between parents and their children or offspring.

As you might know one should obey his parents unless they ask you to do something sinful (see for example [Surat al-Isra' (17:23)](http://quran.com/17/23)  and [Surat Luqman (31:15)](http://quran.com/31/15))! And in your case your parents don't ask you something in which you disobey Allah! But they might want your best by asking you to concentrate on your studies!
So only if you are sure that you would have spare time and the ability to work for a few hours you might consider working, but be aware if your parents then find out and disagreed it seems better to stop. As one is asked to follow the orders and respect the parents as long as they don't ask you something which is prohibited, but if you made them angry or sad that might create a gap between you and your parents which doesn't seem to go along with the view of Islam of the coherence in a family!
So i would tend to say that if you disobey them -especially after they have given you the order again- this could be regarded as a sinful act, even if your parents might need the financial help!

But to make things clear i would suggest you to clearly explain your point of view and listen to their point of view and maybe you could find a solution that fits!

See also
in [al-Adab al mufrad](http://sunnah.com/adab/1/2) a narration qualified as hassan (as a saying of sahabi () only)

And these two fatwas (in Arabic) [1](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=177727) on the limits of obeying the parents and  [2](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=76303) on the rules of obeying parents!

And finally this article (Arabic) about [obeying parents](http://www.alukah.net/sharia/0/41478/)!

Be aware that most Arabic Fatwas and the narration i quoted tend to analyze and emphasize disobeying from [عقوق](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%88%D9%82/) point of view which may mean causing harm to the parents or not honoring them or humiliating them etc. And this isn't your case!

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score -1):

You should obey your parents
And try to get the permission before doing anything,
you disobey god by disobey your parents in matter like that

Comment: `You should obey your parents` Any references from the Quran or Sunnah?

Comment: "Thy Lord hath decreed that ye worship none but Him, and that ye be kind to parents. Whether one or both of them attain old age in thy life, say not to them a word of contempt, nor repel them but address them, in terms of honor." (Qur'an 17:23)

Comment: On the authority of Al-Mughirah (R.A.), who said: The Prophet (S.A.W.) said: "God forbids all of you to disobey your mothers." -(Bukhari and Muslim)

Comment: Ayah clearly doesn't mention obey (being kind is not the same as obeying). The hadith is a lie, at least in its form, the hadith mentions to be dutiful (http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/6), not obey. Obey ones parent was never in the Quran or Sunnah.